# How to select or deselect radio button in python / glade

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, button

As in topic, how can I select or deselect radio buttons in python.
The application is made by quickly.

any help pleas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like checkboxes, radio buttons also inherit from `Gtk.ToggleButton`, so you can use the `set_active()` method to set the status of a radio button. This action causes the `“toggled”` signal to be emitted.

For example, if we have 3 radio buttons called `radio1`, `radio2`, and `radio3` in a group, by default the first one in the group would be selected. If we want to select another one, for example, `radio3` instead, we should use:

```
radio3.set_active(True)
```

### References

- [Python GTK3 Tutorial: Radio Button](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/button_widgets.html#radiobutton)
- [Python GTK3 Tutorial: Toggle Button](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/button_widgets.html#togglebutton)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!